# Prototype class from another library

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to create a prototype class from another library.
The main library is: https://github.com/wakirin/Litepicker
The prototype library is: https://github.com/wakirin/litepicker-module-ranges

I tried to "play" with the configuration of the webpack, but didn't found a working solution.
It works fine with `<script>` tags, but doesn't works with `import`.

```js
console.log('enableModuleRanges' in Litepicker.prototype);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/litepicker@1.2.1/dist/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/litepicker-module-ranges@0.0.1/dist/index.js"></script>
```

And when I try to use `import` (in another Angular project):

```
import Litepicker from 'litepicker';
import 'litepicker-module-ranges';
```

This doesn't work and there are no errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Have a look at [webpack-externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) [exports-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/exports-loader/) and implement it on litepicker alias please.

**Long answer**

The litepicker scripts pushes `Litepicker` object to window so obviously it make sense that when you add the `<script>` tags things are working.

But with webpack:

Webpack compile each module (file - in your case the alias you put for litepicker) with loaders - and output its module.exports or export object into the current file it was imported from.

So let's verify that module.exports/export of the litepicker import is window.Litepicker. This is done with exports-loader. 
Add this loader to your webpack configuration please:

```
{ test: /litepicker/, loader: 'exports-loader?Litepicker=window.Litepicker' }
```

Now this line:

```
import Litepicker from 'litepicker';
```

will transform to something like this in the bundles:

```
var litepicker_1 = __importDefault(__webpack_require__(/*! litepicker */ "litepicker"));
```

and `webpack_window_litepicker('<litepicker_alias>')` will return `module.exports = __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_litepicker__;`

Also,
add it as external configuration:
`externals: {
    Litepicker: 'Litepicker',
  },`

----------------- After cloning waki repo ------------------

1) add alias to litepicker:

```
resolve: {
   alias: {
      'litepicker': 'litepicker/dist/js/main'
   }
}
```

2) Changed loader regex to:

```
{ 
    test: /litepicker\/dist\/js\/main/, 
    loader: 'exports-loader?Litepicker=window.Litepicker'
 }
```

Comment: Still returns `false` from `console.log('enableModuleRanges' in Litepicker.prototype);` in Angular project. Here is commit: https://github.com/wakirin/litepicker-module-ranges/commit/3df0ffcabcd7a709dec9ef775301f1184885ed66 
Did I miss something ?

Comment: add
```externals: {
            'Litepicker': 'Litepicker'
        }``` to webpack configurations file please

Comment: I'll clone the repo and build to see the bundles if this doesn't work, please let me know

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result. Works fine with `<script>`, but not doesn't work with `import` (I am testing in another Angular project).

Comment: I see you didn't define an alias for litepicker,
I cloned the repo and did the following changes (edit in comment) and the build passes, try this on your angular project

Comment: Still not working, could you create a pull request with correct changes please ?

Comment: sure, can you give razronen github user access please?

Comment: You can use a fork. (https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork). Thanks for your help.

Comment: PR created on your repo

Comment: Thanks, but I see that with these changes the main library (https://github.com/wakirin/Litepicker) is also included in index.js
However, I think found a working solution. In the main library I added `window.Litepicker = Litepicker;` and in the prototype library added `const Litepicker = window.Litepicker;` without import the main library. Now it works with `<script>` and `import`. Seems like `alias` and `exports-loader` doesn't required.